# How to Get Entity In Projection

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I hava Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "story", schema = "")
@Data
public class Story implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long sID;
    @Column(name = "vnName", nullable = false)
    private String vnName;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(name = "sUpdate", length = 19)
    private Date sUpdate;
}
```

And Projection Interface:

```
public interface NewStory {
    Story getStory();    
    Long getCnt();      
}
```

And Repository:

```
public interface StoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Story, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT s.* , COUNT(u.chID) as Cnt"
            + " FROM Story s" 
            + " LEFT JOIN Chapter c ON s.sID = c.sID"
            + " LEFT JOIN _ufavorites u ON c.chID = u.chID"
            + " GROUP BY s.sID" + " ORDER BY COUNT(u.chID) DESC", 
            nativeQuery = true)
    public List<NewStory> getStoryNew();

}
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "story": null,
        "cnt": 7
    },...
]
```

Or could it be done in a different way?

Comment: You can find nice example here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/jpa21/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/resultsetmappings